# Providing a generic controlbar for my custom RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a custom `RichTextBox` and want to provide a short and easy way to add EditingCommands on the client-side, e.g. Bold, Italic, Underline:
[image]

So, I just added this property in my `MyRichTextBox` and bound it to an `ItemsControl` in `Generic.xaml`

```
public ItemCollection EditingCommands { get; } = new DataGrid().Items;
```

The usage in the client looks really straight-forward ;-):

```
<c:MyRichTextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <c:MyRichTextBox.EditingCommands>
        <Button Content="B" FontWeight="Bold" ToolTip="Bold: Ctrl+B" Width="20"
                Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" />
        <Button Content="I" FontStyle="Italic" ToolTip="Italic: Ctrl+I" Width="20"
                Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" />
        <Button ToolTip="Underline: Ctrl+U" Width="20"
                Command="EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline">
            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="U" Padding="0" Margin="0" />
        </Button>
    </c:MyRichTextBox.EditingCommands>
</c:MyRichTextBox>
```

But I want to reuse the control several times, so I would like to set the EditingCommands by a style, e.g.

```
<Style x:Key="MyRichTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type c:MyRichTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="EditingCommands">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Button Content="B" FontWeight="Bold" ToolTip="Bold: Ctrl+B" Width="20"
                Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" />
            <Button Content="I" FontStyle="Italic" ToolTip="Italic: Ctrl+I" Width="20"
                Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" />
            <Button ToolTip="Underline: Ctrl+U" Width="20"
                Command="EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline">
                <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="U" Padding="0" Margin="0" />
            </Button>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But that's impossible because `EditingCommands` is not a dependency property. As well as converting to dependency property is not suitable with the type `ItemCollection`.

Actually I'm wondering: Is that the right track for the main goal at all? Putting `Button`s into a `ItemCollection`? Has anyone a better idea? Maybe `ButtonModel`s in concert with a `DataTemplate`?

Comment: But why? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37169/WPF-RichText-Editor

Comment: @Mat Sorry, I don't understand your question. - Regarding to the sample code: I would like to have a control where I can decide on client-side which commands are in the toolbar and which are not. The sample doesn't reflect that in any way.

Comment: I think you have a xy problem.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem This is why I'm asking "But why?". IMHO It seems that you want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that the right track for the main goal at all? Putting Buttons into a ItemCollection? Has anyone a better idea?

You could create your own custom collection and add a dependency property of this type to your custom RichTextBox class:

```
public class CustomItemCollection : ObservableCollection<UIElement>
{
}

public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditingCommandsProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("EditingCommands", typeof(CustomItemCollection),
         typeof(MyRichTextBox));

    public CustomItemCollection EditingCommands
    {
        get { return (CustomItemCollection)GetValue(EditingCommandsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditingCommandsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

You can then set the property in a Style setter:

```
<Style x:Key="MyRichTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type c:MyRichTextBox}" x:Shared="False">
    <Setter Property="EditingCommands">
        <Setter.Value>
            <c:CustomItemCollection>
                <Button Content="B" FontWeight="Bold" ToolTip="Bold: Ctrl+B" Width="20" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" />
                <Button Content="I" FontStyle="Italic" ToolTip="Italic: Ctrl+I" Width="20" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" />
                <Button ToolTip="Underline: Ctrl+U" Width="20" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline">
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="U" Padding="0" Margin="0" />
                </Button>
            </c:CustomItemCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Displaying the buttons is a matter of modifying the template of the MyRichTextBox class to include an ItemsControl that binds to the EditingCommands property, e.g.:

```
<c:MyRichTextBox>
    <c:MyRichTextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="c:MyRichTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyRichTextBoxStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="c:MyRichTextBox">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding EditingCommands}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                            <RichTextBox />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </c:MyRichTextBox.Style>
</c:MyRichTextBox>
```

Comment: That doesn't work if I try to reuse the `MyRichTextBoxStyle`: *Only the last instance of `MyRichTextBox` gets the instance of `CustomItemCollection`.*

Comment: @Marcel try x:Shared="False" on the Style so the same instance of the Style is not reused.

Comment: @Marcel BTW, I don't like to do that normally so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: @AdamCaviness If you have a better solution feel free to post.

Comment: Ok, in absence of alternatives I would call it Solved. (I read https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970778.aspx to understand and prevent side effects but cannot find a reason aganst `x:Shared="False"`.)